# spring mvc form:select option not displaying in screen but is there in HTML source

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp-tags

I am using the spring MVC model attribute approach. When opening a screen i got to read a JSON string and create a map. Display the map in a drop down list. I could see the values in HTML source code but not seeing the drop down in the screen.

```
@RequestMapping("/xxx")
public ModelAndView saws(Map<String, Object> model1) throws IOException {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("xxx");
    model.addObject("message", this.welcome);
    Map<String, String> offers = engine.getOffers();
    model.addObject("offers", offers);//map of offers
    model.addObject("inputs", new inputs());
    return model;

}
```

JSP

```
<form:form action="getoffers" method="get" modelAttribute="inputs">
<body>
<table align="center">
        <tr class="blank_row">
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blank_row">
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <th span
                style="color: red; font-weight: bold; word-wrap: break-word;"
                align="center">Select the service to view current offers</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:select path="offers">
                    <form:options items="${offers}" />
                </form:select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And in the screen i don't see the drop down.when i check the source code I see this. Pls see the pictures

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you already had the sping-mvc dependency.

The html source file is not supposed to have `<form:...>` prefix. It is not rendered correctly.

Put this in your jsp file:
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`

I highly recommend that you use Thymeleaf template engine instead of JSP. The reasons are too long to fit in this answer area.

Comment: spot on.that worked.Sure I shall look into thymeleaf

Comment: @Shiv you're welcome. It's also because your question has enough details.

Comment: Thank You for your generous comment